# I need make a post request to laradock api. Post on postman works but in curl don't

Tags: laravel, docker, curl, post, laradock

I've tried get some response on laradock application, with POST on postman with the same url and works but with curl don't

i've alredy tried change the port, my ip/localhost
but nothing works.

if i change url to localhost:port/xxx don't work, i get nothing as response

function to make a post with curl:

````php
...
$url = '189.xx.xx.xx:81/api/xxxxx/';
   $curl = curl_init();
   curl_setopt($curl... //all the curl settings
...
  $response = curl_exec($curl);```


and my response is "Failed to connect to 189.xx.xx.xx port 81: Connection refused"
````

Comment: Are you sending user agent in curl headers? Maybe can fix your problem.

Comment: You can generate the code from postman and compare.

Comment: i generate the code from postman and works!!! thank you thomas